# How can I ask a question about whether a rule exists in any form of a sport?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want to ask a question in the basic form of:

> Does any form (league, level, conference, etc.) of Sport *X* have (or lack) a rule specifically permitting (or disallowing) *Y*?

Are such questions allowed on this site? Should all questions about whether a rule exists be qualified with a specific sports league, conference, level, etc., or are general questions such as this allowed? For example, "Are there any baseball leagues that allow players to play barefoot?" Is that question *too broad*? Should it instead be phrased as "Are baseball players allowed to play barefoot?"? Would the question *need* to be narrowed down to something like "Are MLB baseball players allowed to play barefoot?"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trouble with "any league" questions isn't fundamentally that they're too broad - it's that the answers quite possibly aren't interesting to anyone. If the rules of my backyard baseball league with my friends allow us to play barefoot, *nobody cares* other than me and my friends.

We don't necessarily need to go as restrictive as "MLB" (unless that's all you care about), but some kind of qualifier which means that answers are going to be from leagues a reasonable number of other people care about is probably necessary. For baseball, "any US professional league" or "any US, Japanese or Korean professional league" is definitely fine. "Any professional league" can lead to obscure leagues in countries you don't care about being found - this can certainly be a problem in soccer. The details will depend quite a lot on the sport being played - there is definitely enough interest for question in NFHS (American) football, but I suspect nobody outside the clubs involved cares deeply about the rules of [my local cricket league](https://www.huddersfieldcricketleague.co.uk/pages/rules).